# Xml Serialization and deserialization fails

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I know that this question has already been asked, but I have strange problem and I can't figure out what to do:

```
public static class XmlHelper
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string xml)
    {
        using (var sr = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)xs.Deserialize(sr);
        }
    }

    public static string Serialize(object o)
    {
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
            {
                var xs = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());
                xs.Serialize(xw, o);
                return sw.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    public string Property1 {get;set;}
    public int Property2 {get;set;}
}
```

I'm serializing class:

```
var a = XmlHelper.Serialize(new MyClass{ Property1 = "a", Property2 = 3 });
var b = XmlHelper.Deserialize<object>(a);
```

Error: There is an error in XML document (1, 41).

Edit: I want to deserialize a as object, is it possible?

Comment: What line does it fail on?

Comment: Is your XML well formed?

Comment: Can you show the object?

Comment: With `XmlSerializer`, the trick is always to look at the `.InnerException`, and then the `.InnerException` of that, and so on. It actually usually does a good job of telling you what the problem is, if you know where to look.

Comment: @James that'll be `return (T)xs.Deserialize(sr);`, from the message

Comment: please post the xml you are trying to deserialize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't passing in the correct type for serialization, change your code to:

```
public static string Serialize<T>(T o)
{
    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
        {
            var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            xs.Serialize(xw, o);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
}
...
// we don't need to explicitly define MyClass as the type, it's inferred
var a = XmlHelper.Serialize(new MyClass{ Property1 = "a", Property2 = 3 });
var b = XmlHelper.Deserialize<MyClass>(a);
```

Comment: In real situation I want to serialize as MyClass and deserialize as object, is it possible?

Comment: @karaxuna That doesn't seem to make sense to me. Just treat it as an object? `object b = XmlHelper.Deserialize<MyClass>(a)`? Or do you mean you want to run the deserializer not knowing which type at compile time?

Comment: Yes, when I'm deserializing it, I don't know it's type

Comment: AFAIK you can't do this. The serializer needs to know the destination type so it can map the properties correctly. Alternatively you could switch to using `JavaScriptSerializer`/`DataContractJsonSerializer` and serialize your data as JSON instead, that way you can deserialize without knowing the type.